# How to use If statement to transfer a cell value from sheet1 to sheet 2 in Google Sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transfer

I just want to know if its possible to use the `IF` STATEMENT in Google Sheets by such algorithm as follows;

On Sheet1, from Cell `A1`, I have a value `blue`, and if the value inside the cell is `blue`, it should be transferred in Sheet2, I don't know if the syntax is correct, but it's something like this.

```
=if A1 VALUE(Blue) then TRANSFER to sheet2 else FALSE;
```

Just to interpret how should it work, but I know the code is wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too clear if this is the result you want, but perhaps something similar:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:E19,"select A, D, C, E, B where A like 'makati%'",1)
```

See my added sheet, Makita-GK, in your sample.

Is that doing what you want?  If not, please provide more details of what you want the result to be.  Note that I added some data values in your Sheet1 data.  If that isn't the type of data you have, please adjust it accordingly.

If necessary, please update your question to clarify the following.

Do you mean "where D='makati'...." or "where A='makati'...."? Column D is lastname in your sample data. Also, you had no data values with makati1 or makati2 in column A?

Comment: Thats Exactly What I want!, I Just want to transfer the rows only with 'makati-value' on site column, including the other columns, but in a different alignment. You guys are really a life saver for students like me who want to learn such things. stackoverflow hasn't been this really helpful before! Especially this pandemic where the individuals like me needs to learn by myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** *(following OP's [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886867/how-to-use-if-statement-to-transfer-a-cell-value-from-sheet1-to-sheet-2-in-googl#comment111208808_62887027))*

You could use a `QUERY` for that. As an example

For `makati1` use


```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:E19,"where A='makati'")
```

Change the name of the sites to get corresponding results.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This `IF` formula will do what you need:

```
=IF('Sheet1'!A1="blue","blue")
```

You can also use:

```
=IF('Sheet1'!A1="blue",'Sheet1'!A1)
```

OR


```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="blue",INDEX(Sheet1!A1))
```

OR

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="blue",INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1"))
```

Functions used:

- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Hi there! you absolutely nailed whats inside my mind. But what exactly I want is, if its possible to transfer all the column values in a single row?  Like for example I have 4 columns, Lastname, Firstname, Cell #, and colorcode, lets say the first row values is Davids, Angelo, 0923-235-0339, blue. when the colorcode value is blue, all the values in that row will be transferred to sheet2. Is that possible?

Comment: *"if its possible to transfer all the column values in a single row"*. Sorry. I lost you there. can you please explain that? Even better, share a test sheet with example and expected results.

Comment: Hi there Marikamitsos! I really appreciate all of these, to be more easier, I created a google sheet to share with you, here's the link- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qa3Hq-jB407Y4qNm0KbO2UI0deBWQIiCtn0CNOcZekg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your sheet is private. Please make it public.

Comment: Done - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qa3Hq-jB407Y4qNm0KbO2UI0deBWQIiCtn0CNOcZekg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hello there marikamitsos, is it possible to use =importRange to copy a single row to another spreadsheet with different link?

Comment: If you mean can you pull a row from another sheet, using `IMPORTRANGE`, the answer is yes.   The format would be:   ```IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hh2grfB6rp9OQ2yAIu3S5YF_CCFJGwyqPGveABlOZKg/edit", "World Cup!A1:E1")``` to copy Row1 columns A to E, from another sheet, to the current cell location.

Comment: If you mean can you push a row to another sheet, not with formulas - that would require using Google scripting, ie. a macro.

Comment: It Works! HAHAHAH, returning to the old one, where sheet1 infos, transferred to another sheet tab, is it possible to change the alignment of the columns on the entire row?

Comment: On makati sheet I want it to show like, =QUERY(Sheet1!A2:E19,"where D='makati' ,  D= makati1'  ,  'D= makati2'  ")      is it possible?, and also the alignment on sheet1 where, site, email, firstname, lastname, cell#,   Can I show the alignment on makati sheet as site, lastname, firstname, cell#, email??